# jclouds publickey auth failed - exhausted available authentication methods

Tags: ssh, amazon-web-services, jclouds, sshj

I've been following the instructions the jcloud example https://github.com/jclouds/jclouds-examples/tree/master/compute-basics. I installed maven, and the program. I see VMs get created on Amazon, but the "echo hello" test at the end of the add node fails, as does trying to do an 'exec ls'. I added a random id_rsa I generated with puttygen. It looks like the code is telling it to use that, but Amazon is using a different key?

```
-  <<authenticated>> woke to: net.schmizz.sshj.userauth.UserAuthException: publickey auth failed
...(attempt 1 of 7): Exhausted available authentication methods
```

Comment: I've tried changing the NodeMetadata node = getOnlyElement to use installPrivateKey with my key, instead of the default templateBuilder.build, but I get the same error. I tried logging into Amazon with putty using my username and key and that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it was because I didn't have a valid id_rsa.pub. You have to have one, and puttygen doesn't produce anything in that format. So use "ssh-keygen -t rsa"